# How do I compare objects in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

How do I compare two objects of a custom class? My idea was to add an additional method to the class in which I can compare the current object with another object of the same kind.

So I can write my own code how each field of the class is compared.

This is how I would do it. Or are there some predefined methods to do that? Like "isEqualTo" of the NSString class?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The pointers to `-isEqual:` are good, but if you implement `-isEqual:`, you absolutely *must* also implement `-hash` in such a way that if two objects return `YES` for `-isEqual:` they will also return the same value for `-hash`. Implementing `isEqual:` without also implementing `-hash` leads to some very surprising bugs when you use Collections like NSArray.

For new developers, I tend to recommend against overloading `-isEqual:`. I recommend instead using the same technique as NSString, and create a custom `-isEqualToFoo:` (where `Foo` is your class) until you understand the impact of `-isEqual:` on collections and specifically want this behavior. Overloading `-isEqual:` powerful, but the bugs you can create are subtle. Creating your own custom comparator is safer and clearer in many cases.

Comment: Hi Rob. Great answer! Since I am a "new developer" I will do exactly as you suggested. This is what I had in mind in the first place.  Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. While I still don't understand WHY isEqual isn't enough to determine equality, I was getting some REALLY strange NSCountedSet behavior because I had no idea that hash came into play with generic equality testing.

Comment: @LucasTizma You need to implement `hash` because its used for optimizations. `isEqual:` might be very expensive. Consider a massive `NSString`. You have to compare every character. Instead, you first check `hash`. This is a simple number, so the comparison is very fast, and for bucket-like data structures you've already calculated it anyway. If the hashes are equal, only then is `isEqual:` called. It's ok for two unequal things to have the same hash, and the simplest legal hash method is `return 1;`. But this can hurt performance if there are many equality checks and `isEqual:` is expensive.

Answer (score 6):

The standard way is to override `- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject` and `- (NSUInteger)hash`.

You should read the documentation for [NSObject protocol](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254281/best-practices-for-overriding-isequal-and-hash/254337) SO question has some interesting answers on how to write your hash method.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `isEqual:` and the `compare:` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following object:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, SeasonType) {
    kWinter,
    kSpring,
    kSummer,
    kFall
};

@interface Season : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) SeasonType season;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger year;

+(id) seasonWithYear:(NSInteger)year season:(SeasonType)season;
-(id) initWithYear:(NSInteger)year season:(SeasonType)season;

@end
```

What I do is overwrite base NSObject comparison methods, there's no need of reinventing the wheel and code keeps cleaner as well:

```
#import "Season.h"

@interface Season()

@end

@implementation Season

+(id) seasonWithYear:(NSInteger)year season:(SeasonType)season{
    return [[self alloc] initWithYear:year season:season];
}

-(id) initWithYear:(NSInteger)year season:(SeasonType)season{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _year = year;
        _season=season;
        _baseDate=nil;
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - NSObject

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    if (self == object) {
        return YES;
    }

    if (![object isKindOfClass:[Season class]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return [self _isEqualToSeason:(Season *)object];
}

- (NSUInteger)hash {
    return self.season ^ self.year;
}


#pragma mark - Private/Internal

- (BOOL)_isEqualToSeason:(Season *)season {
    if (!season) {
        return NO;
    }

    return ((!self.season && !season.season) || self.season == season.season) &&
    ((!self.year && !season.year)    ||  self.year == season.year) ;
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
Season *season2 = [Season seasonWithYear:2010 season:kFall];
Season *season3 = [Season seasonWithYear:2009 season:kFall];
[season2 isEqual:season3];
```