# iOS How do I compare if Objects are Equal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a list of Objects that I pull from a web service.  When I update my UITableView, I retrieve the objects again from the web service, and compare them to each other for equality. I then remove the ones that are not present, and insert the new objects, then update my  UITableView. How can I test to see if the new object equals the old object? I've created a test for clarity..

requestA should equal requestC, but fails.

Is this possible to do without looking at each property value as the objects have many values?

I was originally comparing the ID only, but this doesn't work as sometimes other property values change and the ID stays the same.

```
    Request *requestA = [[Request alloc] init];
    Request *requestB = [[Request alloc] init];
    Request *requestC = [[Request alloc] init];

    requestA.requestID = @"1";
    requestA.productName = @"Clutch";
    requestB.requestID = @"2";
    requestB.productName = @"Wiper";
    requestC.requestID = @"1";
    requestC.productName = @"Clutch";

    if (requestA == requestB)
        NSLog(@"A == B");

    if (requestA == requestC)
        NSLog(@"A == C");

    if ([requestA isEqual:requestB])
        NSLog(@"A isEqual B");

    if ([requestA isEqual:requestC])
        NSLog(@"A isEqual C");

    // Look at the pointers:
    NSLog(@"%p", requestA);
    NSLog(@"%p", requestB);
    NSLog(@"%p", requestC);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isEqual:` is a method declared in `NSObject Protocol`. From official docs of `isEqual`:

> This method defines what it means for instances to be equal. For
>   example, a container object might define two containers as equal if
>   their corresponding objects all respond YES to an isEqual: request.
>   See the NSData, NSDictionary, NSArray, and NSString class
>   specifications for examples of the use of this method.
>
> If two objects are equal, they must have the same hash value. This
>   last point is particularly important if you define isEqual: in a
>   subclass and intend to put instances of that subclass into a
>   collection. Make sure you also define hash in your subclass.

Thus, as Salavat Khanov pointed out in his answer:

> You need to implement -isEqual: and -hash methods for your Request class.

You want to do something like this:

```
// TestRequest.h
@interface TestRequest : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *requestID;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *productName;

@end

// TestRequest.m
#import "TestRequest.h"

@implementation TestRequest
- (BOOL)isEqual:(TestRequest *)object {
    if (self == object) {
        return YES;
    }

    if (![self.requestID isEqual:object.requestID]) {
        return NO;
    }

    if (![self.productName isEqual:object.productName]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)hash {
    // this is a very simple hash function
    return [self.requestID hash] ^ [self.productName hash];
}
@end
```

or you can use a custom method:

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToRequest:(TestRequest *)otherRequest {
    return [self.requestID isEqualToString:otherRequest.requestID] && 
           [self.productName isEqualToString:otherRequest.productName];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Check this answer: [How do I compare objects in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876866/how-do-i-compare-objects-in-objective-c)

You need to implement `-isEqual:` and `-hash` methods for your `Request` class.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful, I accepted @wcd, just because it gave me some examples, but this is the implementation I used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite `isEqual:` of your Request object to specify the properties to compare.
Write sth. like this:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)other {
    if (other == self) return YES;
    if (!other || ![other isKindOfClass:[self class]]) return NO;
    if (![(id)[self name] isEqual:[other name]]) return NO;
    // add other checks if needed
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You neglected to mention that you must also implement `hash`. ALWAYS implement both methods together.

Answer (score 0):

First off. == is a check for "are these two objects actually the SAME OBJECT". I.e. They are just two pointers to the same but of memory.

You need to be using the `isEqual` method. However, in order to do this properly you need to override the method in the class.

Something like...

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(Request *)otherObject
{
    return [self.productName isEqual:otherObject.productName]
    && [self.requestID isEqual:otherObject.requestID];
}
```

Comment: You neglected to mention that you must also implement `hash`. ALWAYS implement both methods together.