# Send object in function & comparison them to coincidence with other objects

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, selector, nsobject, compareobject

I want to send some object to function for check it and set him some data.

For example:
i have 4 properties (with int type) of self class (inherit from NSObject class). And i want to change their data in one function. I must send dress of this properties into function, check it to compare with this dresses of this properties: `self.opt1`, `self.opt2`, `self.opt3`, `self.opt4`, and set them some values.

I try to create function:

`- (void)setupMultiplierForObject:(id)object`

but i don't know how i can check `object` argument to comparison `self.opt1` (object to object, not their values).

What if must set into `if (<here>) {}` construction?

Comment: Maybe [object isKindOfClass: [self.opt1 class]] is what you want?

Comment: All this objects is equal to one class.. I think it's not be helpful.. I must compare objects id (in my opinion)...

Comment: Than I guess you should look at isEqual API https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectComparison.html

Comment: isEqual compare values of objects, not same object or their id...

Comment: Lol WAT? isEqual compares pointers actually.

Comment: Look at the example (table) of isEqual - it's check values of objects, not object id. Maybe I can't explain what I want. I will try one more time: If (object is self.opt1) object = 1 elseif (object is self.opt2) object = 2......

Comment: Have you tried == operator? Like so, object == self.opt1

Comment: Operator == compare values too. I don't need compare values..) I want to check: is sending into function object - is this object (self.opt1 for example). And set to this object (which was referred) new value...

Comment: Take a look at this thread. You should override isEqual and hash methods in you custom class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876866/how-do-i-compare-objects-in-objective-c

Comment: I fix-it, see answer! )

Answer (score 0):

I fix-it with next construction:

```
[self setupMultiplierForObject:&((*self).time1)];
```

`- (void)setupMultiplierForObject:(int*)object {
if (object == &((*self).time1)) {
// Doing something with self.time1, because we know that ended object - is self.time1
}
}`