# checking if an array doesn't contain a certain object

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

is there a class available to check if an array doesn't contain an object?
I want to do something like

```
if [(myarray doesntContain @"object")]
```

is this possible

Comment: @Alx, when you're choosing the tags for your question, it's generally a good idea to make sure one of them is the language you're asking the question for =)

Comment: In which case, which sort of array? A basic C array, or a NSArray?

Comment: Remember to add those details to the question when asking, most of us can't read minds.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

For `NSArray` use [`-containsObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#jumpTo_17):

```
if (![myarray containsObject:someObject]) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i know about contains object
i want to see if there isnt a specific object in the array and if there isnt to add one. i know how to add i just dont know how to check if an object is missing..

Comment: @Alx: Thats why the `!` is there, its basically *"if not (array containsObject)"*. There isn't a specific `-doesntContainObject:` as its trivial to use `!` or `== NO`.

Comment: however one small error i have
 if (![self.favoritesArray containsObject:@"added"]) {
        [self.favoritesArray addObject:@"added"];
    }
    
    else if
        ([self.favoritesArray containsObject:@"added"])
    {
        [self.favoritesArray removeObject:@"added"];
    }

this is my code and when i press the button it doesn remove the added option...

Comment: @Alx: You can't add or remove objects with a `NSArray`, use `NSMutableArray`. If you still have problems then, you should open a new question and add some more details. Also note that `if (!...) { ... } else { ... }` is sufficient (you don't have to test twice) and that maybe `NSMutableSet` would be a better fit for you.

Comment: i know and my array is a mutable one.

Comment: By the way: if your array consists of custom objects you created, you need to implement `-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)anotherObject;` method on them in order to `-containsObject:` work properly

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an NSArray category to achieve these negated checks via  instance methods, as you had originally requested..  The first is for an array-type set group of objects, the latter for a singular check.  These return YES in the case that the array instance DOES NOT contain the passed object or objects.  Why?  Exclamation marks confuse me.

*NSArray+Additions.h*

`-(BOOL)doesNotContainObjects:(id<NSFastEnumeration>)enumerable;`

`-(BOOL)doesNotContainObject:(id)object;`

*NSArray+Additions.m*

```
-(BOOL)doesNotContainObjects:(id<NSFastEnumeration>)enumerable {
   for (id x in enumerable) {
     if ([self containsObject:x]) return NO; // exists, abort!
   }
   return YES;   // it ain't in there, return TRUE;
}
- (BOOL)doesNotContainObject:(id)object {
  if ([self containsObject:object]) return NO; return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with an NSArray, your first port of call should probably be the [Apple documentation for NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray), and probably the method [containsObject](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject:), there's an example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941596/nsarray-containobjects-method).

Comment: i know about contains object
i want to see if there isnt a specific object in the array and if there isnt to add one. i know how to add i just dont know how to check if an object is missing..

Comment: So invert the call to `containsObject` as Georg has indicated in his answer =)