# Checking if an array contains a certain object (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I need to check if a certain array contains a certain object, and if it does, delete that object. If it hasn't got that object, the funciton is suposed to add it into the array. The problem is that the object is always added because the checking statement always return false.

Here's my current function:

```
- (void) myFunction:(NSString *)parameter {

    if (![myMutableArray containsObject:parameter]) {

        [myMutableArray addObject:parameter];
        NSLog(@"%@ added", parameter);

    } else {

        [myMutableArray removeObject:parameter];
        NSLog(@"%@ deleted", parameter);

    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you are having the same issue as was solved in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941596/nsarray-containobjects-method

Comment: Is the array purely an array of NSString objects?

Comment: What happens if you call your method twice with the same parameter?

Comment: Do you want to check if you have the same object (meaning same memory address, etc) or just an equal string (like @"a" 'is equal to' @"a")?

Comment: Yes, all objects are strings and when I try to call the method twice with the same parameter, I just return `deleted` in my console

Comment: That would suggest that your original string and the new one are different somehow -- case, whitespace, etc.

Comment: Your code works with 2 different arrays: `myMutableArray` and `myMutbaleArray`. That would explain the problem if it is your actual code.

Comment: Corrected. But that wasn't the problem

Comment: @iosdevrocks: It is always better to copy/paste the actual code into the question, instead of re-typing it.

Comment: I've checked again the code and I've realized that the problem is that any object is added. Maybe the problem is in the `addObject` function. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you instantiated `myMutableArray`?

Comment: Have you verified that myMutableArray is *allocated+initialized*? (See mprivat's answer.)

Comment: Yes it was instantiated but the function wasn't called due to another issue that I've just fixed. Thanks! Problem solved

Comment: check another alternet solution i have given in the answer.

Comment: For future folks that may encounter similar symptoms, what "issue" did you find?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

containsObject is calling isEqual on each of the object in the arrays. What type of object are you checking for? If it's a custom object, override and implement the method isEqual.

I'm guessing you're trying to check the value of the object, but containsObject is actually calling isEqual which is comparing the reference to the object, and not its actual value.

Answer (score 22):

```
if (![arrList containsObject:arrObj]) {
    // do something
}
```

[containsObject:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject:)

Answer (score 7):

First you need to check which type data or object you are adding in this `myMutableArray`. According to your method you are checking in mutable array for string type that you have passed argument `parameter`. It may be possible that you are containing int or float array.

There may be issue of type casting in your array.If your is STRING type of data then you can  use another method like this.

```
- (void) myFunction:(NSString *)parameter {

for (int i = 0 ; i < [myMutableArray count ] ; i++) {


    if (![[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:parameter]) {
        [myMutableArray addObject:parameter];
        NSLog(@"%@ added", parameter);
    }
    else{
        [myMutableArray removeObject:parameter];
        NSLog(@"%@ deleted", parameter);
    }
}
```

}

Hope this will help you. If your object is not type of NSString then you need to convert.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement `isEqual:` in your custom class. By default two objects are only identical if they share the same reference.

Also make sure to initialize your mutable array before using it.

**EDIT**:

It seems that your array's variable name are most probably mistyped.

- `myMutableArray`
- `myMutbaleArray`

Comment: It's not a custom class, it's a NSString

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to initialize your `NSMutableArray`. If not initialized, you are sending `addObject` messages to a `nil` object, which has no effect, and the array never contains what you previously added...

Of course, if the array is `nil`, then the `contains` check will always return false. According to the Objective-C docs:

> If the method returns an object, any pointer type, any integer scalar
>   of size less than or equal to sizeof(void*), a float, a double, a long
>   double, or a long long, then a message sent to nil returns 0.

And 0 is false