# isMemberOfClass vs comparing classes with ==

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, class, rtti, dynamic-cast

Is there any real difference between:

```
id value;
BOOL compare1 = [value isMemberOfClass:[SomeClass class]];
BOOL compare2 = [value class] == [SomeClass class];
```

to check if `value` is a `SomeClass` object?

Comment: Looks to me like isMemberOfClass will also work on derived classes. I don't know Cocoa though, so don't kill me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Jouke, no killing, but you're confusing it with `isKindOfClass:` (**that** is the one which accepts derived classes as well) -- `isMemberOfClass:` checks for specific membership only (admittedly a very rare need;-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `value` is an `NSProxy`, `isMemberOfClass:` will properly check the proxied object, the other construct, I believe, won't (I think it will clumsily duplicate `isProxy:`).

Comment: Yup -- you are correct (I forgot about NSProxy).  Deleted my answer.   Use `isMemberOfClass:` as it is correct always whereas `==` has holes.