# Is there any way to merge two NSMutableArray in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I have two NSMutableArray filled with data object. how do I compare both array and merge if any change found.

ex:
`Array1= index(0) userName = {'a',1,'address'}`
 `index(1) userName = {'b',2,'address'}`

`Array2= index(0) userName = {'c',3,'address'}`
 `index (1) userName = {'b',2,'address'}`

Result is: 
`Array= index(0) userName = {'a',1,'address'}`
     `index (1) userName = {'b',2,'address'}`
          `index(2) userName = {'c',3,'address'}`

Please help

Answer (score 52, accepted):

An easy way is to use sets:

```
NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1];
[set addObjectsFromArray:array2];

NSArray *array = [set allObjects];
```

Though you will have to sort `array` yourself afterward.

(N.B., I used lowercase names for the variables as is usually customary).

Comment: This solution doesn't return unique array for custom objects. Any clue on how to get that to work?

Comment: Answer to my own question above: I missed creating isEqual methods for my custom classes. Here's how I did it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/254281/127036

Answer (score 12):

```
NSArray *array1, *array2;
```

...

```
MSMutableArray *result = [array1 mutableCopy];
for (id object in array2)
  {
  [result removeObject:object];  // make sure you don't add it if it's already there.
  [result addObject:object];
  }
```