# Using NSSet/NSMutableSet to Filter Objects?

Tags: objective-c

I have seen some questions/answers regarding filter objects by using NSSet/NSMutableSet. Those cases use simple type of objects such as `NSString` or `int`. The following is an example of codes used to filter `NSString` objects:

```
NSSet smallArray = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"2", nil];
NSArray bigArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"4", @"5", ..., nil];
NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:smallArray];
[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:bigArray];
NSArray *result = [NSArray arrayWithSet:intersection];
```

I am not sure how it works if objects in set or array are Object-C class instances. Take the following class as example:

```
@interface MyObject: NSObject {
   int id;
   NSString *name;
   NSString *city;
   ...
}
```

I am not sure how set's intersetSet: works with above type objects. If I want to get intersect set of smallArray of `MyObject` objects and bigArray by only comparing id, I doubt if I can use `intersetSet:` selector method? If not, not sure if I should add any method to `MyObject` class so that set knows how to compare objects?

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement [`isEqual:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) (and also [`hash`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash)) on MyObject so that if two objects "match", then it returns YES. Then the set intersection code should work automatically.

[Here's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectComparison.html) a quick and dirty sample from the documentation. Also check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/254281/458922).

Comment: Your answer makes sense. I'll try it first Thanks!