# NSArray of NSSet shows nothing in NSLog

Tags: ios, nsarray, intersection, nsset

```
NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:newsmall];

//this shows an array of newsmall as expected
NSLog(@"intersection %@", intersection);

[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:newnewbig]];

//this shows nothing
NSLog(@"intersection %@", intersection);

//this shows an array of newnewbig as expected
NSLog(@"newnewbig %@", newnewbig);

NSArray *arrayfour = [intersection allObjects];

//this shows nothing
NSLog(@"arrayfour %@", arrayfour);
```

newsmall and newnewbig have some matched strings, so I expect arrayfour to show a couple of strings.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your understanding of how `intersectSet` works.

I think you are expecting it to compare contents of the strings from newsmall and newnewbig, but what it's really doing is comparing object addresses.

Do this before you do the `intersectSet` call:

```
NSUInteger index = 0;
for(NSString * aString in newsmall)
{
    NSLog( @"newsmall string %d is %p %@", index++, aString, aString );
} 

index = 0;
for(NSString * aString in newnewbig)
{
    NSLog( @"newnewbig string %d is %p %@", index++, aString, aString );
}
```

`intersectSet` will only work if the address (the `%p` in the formatting up there) matches.  The string contents might match, but what intersectSet cares about is the string address.

So really, your solution is that you need to do a different way of comparing strings between sets.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `intersectSet`, I think it's comparing pointers, and not the content of your `NSString`.

Have a look here, it may help : [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965259/using-nsset-nsmutableset-to-filter-objects)