# How to handle floats and doubles when implementing -hash in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm a newbie at Objective-C and I'm looking for the best way to handle primitive floats and double when implementing the -hash method in an Objective-C class. I've found some good advise on isEqual and hash in general in this question:

[Best practices for overriding isEqual: and hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254281/best-practices-for-overriding-isequal-and-hash)

but it doesn't say anything on how to deal with floats and doubles.

My best attempt:

```
...
long lat = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.latitude] longValue];
result = prime * result + (int) (lat ^ (lat >>> 32));
...
```

but I'm not sure this is the correct way. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the assumption that Apple's implementation of `-hash` is adequate, what is wrong with

```
result = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble: [self latitude]] hash];
```

Or using the modern syntax

```
result = [@([self latitude]) hash];
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that one and it sure beats my version. Here's what I currently have: `result = 31 * result + [[NSNumber numberWithDouble: self.longitude] hash];` But I still wonder what the "oficial" way is to deal with doubles, since this solution does require some object creation.

Comment: This is (a) type unsafe C and (b) you're not interested in the actual source value just a suitable hash, so... just use the bits. E.g. `UInt64 doubleBits = *(UInt64 *)&doubleVar;` Now you have a `UInt64` to hash and it seems you have an algorithm for that.

Comment: @CRD: How exactly is it type unsafe?  It seems like a perfectly reasonable way to get a hash value to me.

Comment: @JeremyP: C is type unsafe so you can take a "pointer to double" and cast it to "pointer to UInt64" - a type safe language would stop you, and in general doing this should be avoided. However for the purpose of hash generation it does just what you need - gets you the bits. (Of course generating a hash for a floating point value has the same caveats as comparing them for equality, but that is another issue...)

Comment: @CRD: I wasn't casting a double pointer to a uint64_t pointer.  My method was in fact completely type safe.

Comment: @JeremyP: Apologies, my answer wasn't clear - I was answering Age's concern in his comment that "this solution does require some object creation" and *not* saying your solution is type unsafe! It is my solution which is, but it requires no object creation which is probably good in this case.

Answer (score 8):

Advice of @JeremyP about using `NSNumber` was pretty good, but I followed this more into depth. Since CoreFoundation is open source, I found how does `CFNumber` implement hashing function and this is what I found:

**Split the number to integral and fraction part, hash both parts and sum them.** Integral part is hashed by modulo and a hash-factor, fraction part is hashed only by multiplication.

```
NSUInteger HashDouble(double value) {
    double absolute = ABS(value);
    double integral = round(absolute);
    double fragment = absolute - integral;
    NSUInteger integralHash = 2654435761U * fmod(integral, NSUIntegerMax);
    NSUInteger fragmentHash = fragment * NSUIntegerMax;
    return integralHash + fragmentHash;
}
```

---

Original source code from CoreFoundation wth comments:

```
/* For use by NSNumber and CFNumber.
  Hashing algorithm for CFNumber:
  M = Max CFHashCode (assumed to be unsigned)
  For positive integral values: (N * HASHFACTOR) mod M
  For negative integral values: ((-N) * HASHFACTOR) mod M
  For floating point numbers that are not integral: hash(integral part) + hash(float part * M)
  HASHFACTOR is 2654435761, from Knuth's multiplicative method
*/
#define HASHFACTOR 2654435761U

CF_INLINE CFHashCode _CFHashInt(long i) {
    return ((i > 0) ? (CFHashCode)(i) : (CFHashCode)(-i)) * HASHFACTOR;
}

CF_INLINE CFHashCode _CFHashDouble(double d) {
    double dInt;
    if (d < 0) d = -d;
    dInt = floor(d+0.5);
    CFHashCode integralHash = HASHFACTOR * (CFHashCode)fmod(dInt, (double)ULONG_MAX);
    return (CFHashCode)(integralHash + (CFHashCode)((d - dInt) * ULONG_MAX));
}
```

From file [ForFoundationOnly.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/ForFoundationOnly.h) on [opensource.apple.com](http://opensource.apple.com).

Comment: So positive and negative floats have the same hash? Interesting...