# obtaining a property name at Run time using Objective C

Tags: ios, memory-management, objective-c-runtime

with MBaas services getting really affordable, and easy to use, I was wondering if anyone could give me an advice on the following design choice ?

Context: Send the content of an NSDictionary for remote storage. So the idea is to  build a key/value relation, on the fly.

How:
using the piece of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6616013/1772468), it is possible to retrieve the name of an instance variable. so, the key/value relation results from [{ivar_name ="the value I'm interested in  from this ivar"}, etc.... ]

I understand the limitations of the proposed code, but I think they are outweighed by the benefits.

In my case, the dictionary will not live beyond the class life-cycle, so I should not keep strong references on ivars, when the View is removed from the stack. Furthermore, it's going to be NSString taken from TextFields.

However, there is one question I can't really answer: if the ivars I'm looking at are part of reusable UITableViewCells (ex: IBOutlet textField in a UItableviewCell), should I make a copy of the textField.text or can I keep a reference on the string pointed at by textField.text? or it doesn't matter?

Thanks !

Comment: As the textField.text (or any other UIKit `NSString`) property already is qualified as being `copy`, you do not need to care.

Comment: @Till ok, cool. if you put your comment as an answer, I can close my question and vote your answer