# How to get a class's property from a string?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I want to get a class's property from a string.
For example:

```
    NSString * propertyStr = @"propertyStr";
    if ([class haveProperty:propertyStr]) {
        class.propertyStr = @"avalue";
    }
```

I don't know if i have say it clear.

Comment: please ask clear, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615826/get-property-name-as-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since @property and @syn automatically create the getter and setters we can use the below code to check if any class responds to particular message (setter)

```
NSString *propertyStr = @"propertyStr";
if ([class respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(propertyStr)]) 
{
[class setValue:@"Value" forKey:propertyStr];
}
```

Comment: First thank you.And how to judge the property is NSString or int?

Comment: You can check using if([class.propertyStr isKindOfClass[NSString Class]])// Then set the value accordingly otherwise else condition...

Comment: primitives are not subClass of NSObject, hence `isKindOfClass` will not work, will be an compiler error. [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537787/how-to-know-the-type-of-classs-property-from-string/20538879#20538879)

Answer (score 4):

You want to check if your class have property called `propertyStr`, for that you can do :

```
NSString *propertyStr = @"propertyStr";
if ([class respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(propertyStr)]) {
    class.propertyStr = @"avalue";
}
```

Comment: Just updated `if ([class respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(propertyStr)])` it was `if ([self respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(propertyStr)])`

Comment: First thank you.And how to judge the property is NSString or int?

Comment: objective-c runtime is one way to check

Answer (score 1):

Try with **respondsToSelector**

**Syntax**

```
 if ([class respondsToSelector:@selector(property)])
        [[class property] setProperty:@"value"];
```

**Example**

```
if ([UINavigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)])
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

Comment: he wants to access through the string, not directly from the property. So your answer doesn't help him, but I wonder upvotes :D

Comment: @Virussmca: do you give upvote only becuase of first answer or to correct answer?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: i gave sample way that show that is class has property to or not./

Comment: @AnandVyas: But your sample way is not the answer he is asking.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: i just help him to check that it has property or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this..

```
NSString *selName = @"yourPropertyName";
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selName);

if ([className respondsToSelector:selector])
    className.selName = /* your action*/;
```