# Get property name of object as string in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, introspection, objective-c-runtime

Suppose you have a class "Foo" with property "testProperty". The aim is to get property name (not value) as `NSString`. The question is probably duplicate of [Get property name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615826/get-property-name-as-a-string) . But that answers did not help me because:

- I don't need all properties. I need only particular one.
- For `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(prop))` - anyway you have to input string.

Suppose I have a function like

```
- (NSString *)propertyToString:(id)propertyOfObject
```

In that case I can use, for instance, for sorting

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:[self propertyToString:foo.testProperty] ascending:NO];
```

So finally, the code will be clean.

Comment: You said - "I want one particular, not all."...uhm..how exactly would you know which particular one you want, if you didn't know its name? And IF you knew, well just create the string yourself...?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate to the one you linked. Just do as in the answer you linked, and when looping over all properties, just store the one you want and ignore the rest.

Comment: @Michal,I would like to make my code clean, that is why I don't want to use string constants.

Comment: @razor28 It's not clean to hide the name of the property you're using. Imagine the person that takes over your code after you switch to different project. Will he/she know immediately what is going on in your code, if you actually incorporate the name of the property into string, that is not able to be seen unless it's actually running in lldb?

Comment: @Volker, in that case how do I convert Foo.testProperty to objc_property_t ?

Comment: @Michal, suppose I have a function like - (NSString *)propertyToString:(id)propertyOfObject. In that case I can use, for instance, for sorting NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:[self propertyToString:foo.testProperty] ascending:NO]; I guess everything is clean.

Comment: Then do something like #define mySuperSortKey @"testProperty" and use mySuperSortKey

Comment: Is the idea to get the property name based on what object it is currently set to?

Comment: @JeremyP, instance variable of object doesn't matter. The idea is not to use string constants or config files for mapping or comparing purposes.

Comment: It's now clear what this question is asking, the question has been updated with a practical example. Please reopen.

Comment: You can't do what you're asking for. `foo.testProperty` is simply a method call (really, a message send), not some kind of "property entity" like it might be in another language. Using the name of the property is how you do this in ObjC. `@selector(nameOfMethod)` is how you refer to methods, including properties' setters and getters, as things in their own right.

Comment: It's possible, but not at run time, pre-processor macros can achieve this job.

Comment: From [Get property name as string, without using the runtime reference library](http://www.g8production.com/post/78429904103/get-property-name-as-string-without-using-the), just define:  

    `#define propertyKeyPath(property) (@""#property)`  
    `#define propertyKeyPathLastComponent(property) [[(@""#property) componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject]`  

And then you can do something like this:  

    `NSLog(@"%@", propertyKeyPathLastComponent(appleStore.storeLocation.street)); //result: street`

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. You want to get the property name but you need to pass something to distinguish it from other ones.

Comment: The input is foo.testProperty.

Comment: @razor28. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Code's not tested. 
Should be sth like:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

Class cls = [Foo class];
u_int count;
objc_property_t* props = class_copyPropertyList(cls,&count);
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
    NSString* propname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(props[i])];
    if([propname hasPrefix:@"test"])
        NSLog(@"foo");
}
```

Your searching a way to select a subset of the prop sets. Only thing you can do is apply some kind of filter - could be a naming convention of properties like above - to reduce the set of properties to your desired ones.

Comment: The aim is not to use any string constants. The input should be foo.testProperty.