# How to iterate over the properties of my models in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I want to iterate over the properties of my models in Objective-C. I tried this. Created `PropertyUtil` class with method `classPropsFor:(Class)klass`. Please find the attachment. Used `objc/runtime.h`. The code which I got from the net. In my viewcontroller I am doing this. `[PropertyUtil classPropsFor:[self.user class]];`. `self.user` is User model class. What I want to know is how can i iterate over the properties of my models, let's `username`, `password` and those values.

[image: User]

[image: PropertyUtil][image: Description]
[image: Finally]

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615826/get-property-name-as-a-string

Comment: Do not show pictures of code.

Comment: A note about this code...the `getPropertyType` method has an error in that it returns a pointer to memory owned by an NSData object. After the return, under ARC, that memory will be freed so your result pointer is pointing to memory whose contents may change. I had a crash caused by this so I modified the code to use malloc for my result buffer. The caller to the `getPropertyType` function is responsible for freeing the returned pointer.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to manually list all properties your model has. 
Just add a method to your model:

```
+(NSArray*) propList {
    return @[@"prop1", @"prop2"];
}
```

Then just use key-value coding to get the value

```
[someObject valueForKey:@"prop1"];
```

That's pretty straight and simple way if you wish to avoid Obj-C meta functions. Since you add your properties manually anyway, you may also add them in your list as well.

That's of course, if you don't have a large amount of models already and you wish do them all at once.