# NSArray: Remove objects with duplicate properties

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I have an NSMutableArray that contains a few custom objects.  Two of the objects have the same properties such as title and author.  I want to remove the duplicate object and leave the other.

```
Asset *asset;
NSMutableArray *items = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

// First
asset = [[Asset alloc] init];
asset.title = @"Developer";
asset.author = @"John Smith";
[items addObject:asset];
[asset release];

// Second
asset = [[Asset alloc] init];
asset.title = @"Writer";
asset.author = @"Steve Johnson";
[items addObject:asset];
[asset release];

// Third
asset = [[Asset alloc] init];
asset.title = @"Developer";
asset.author = @"John Smith";
[items addObject:asset];
[asset release];
```

**Since they are NOT the same object, but only having duplicate properties, how can I remove the duplicate?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could create a HashSet and as you loop, you could add "title+author" concatenated set to the HashSet (NSMutableSet).  As you arrive at each item, if the HashSet contains your key, either remove it or don't copy (either deleting or creating a copy without duplicates).

That makes it order n (1 loop)

Here's the NSMutableSet class:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableSet

**EDIT with code:**

The meat of the code is the one loop.

```
void print(NSMutableArray *assets)
{
    for (Asset *asset in assets)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@/%@", [asset title], [asset author]);
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    //
    // Create the initial data set
    //
    Asset *asset;
    NSMutableArray *items = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    // First
    asset = [[Asset alloc] init];
    asset.title = @"Developer";
    asset.author = @"John Smith";
    [items addObject:asset];
    [asset release];

    // Second
    asset = [[Asset alloc] init];
    asset.title = @"Writer";
    asset.author = @"Steve Johnson";
    [items addObject:asset];
    [asset release];

    // Third
    asset = [[Asset alloc] init];
    asset.title = @"Developer";
    asset.author = @"John Smith";
    [items addObject:asset];
    [asset release];

    NSLog(@"****Original****");
    print(items);

    //
    // filter the data set in one pass
    //
    NSMutableSet *lookup = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    for (int index = 0; index < [items count]; index++)
    {
        Asset *curr = [items objectAtIndex:index];
        NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [curr title], [curr author]];

        // this is very fast constant time lookup in a hash table
        if ([lookup containsObject:identifier])
        {
            NSLog(@"item already exists.  removing: %@ at index %d", identifier, index);
            [items removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"distinct item.  keeping %@ at index %d", identifier, index);
            [lookup addObject:identifier];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"****Filtered****");
    print(items);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Craplet[11991:707] ****Original****
Craplet[11991:707] Developer/John Smith
Craplet[11991:707] Writer/Steve Johnson
Craplet[11991:707] Developer/John Smith
Craplet[11991:707] distinct item.  keeping Developer/John Smith at index 0
Craplet[11991:707] distinct item.  keeping Writer/Steve Johnson at index 1
Craplet[11991:707] item already exists.  removing: Developer/John Smith at index 2
Craplet[11991:707] ****Filtered****
Craplet[11991:707] Developer/John Smith
Craplet[11991:707] Writer/Steve Johnson
```

Comment: So you are saying add an add an NSString object to the NSMutableSet then on the next loop check of that same string exists?

Comment: Yes - in one pass, you're trying to see if you've already seen a similar items.  You have to identify what similar means (in this case title + author).  The NSSet offers very fast lookup (using a hash internally) to answer that question quickly.  The one downside is extra memory for the distinct set of title+author combos.  Typical space vs. time.

Comment: Ok, still confused how I then do the lookup with the NSSet. Could you offer a quick code example?

Comment: I didn't notice before I posted that NSSet containsObject is constant time, O(1)!  That's actually awesome.  I was going to dispute that this algorithm is linear, but if containsObject is truly constant time, then yeah it is.  Well done, @bryanmac!

Comment: Awesome! I needed to add "index --" when i removed object

Answer (score 4):

You can use the uniqueness of an `NSSet` to get distinct items from your original array. If you have the source code for `Assest` you will need to override the [`hash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254281/best-practices-for-overriding-isequal-and-hash) and `isEqual:` method on the `Asset` class.

```
@interface Asset : NSObject
@property(copy) NSString *title, *author;
@end

@implementation Asset
@synthesize title, author;

-(NSUInteger)hash
{
    NSUInteger prime = 31;
    NSUInteger result = 1;

    result = prime * result + [self.title hash];
    result = prime * result + [self.author hash];

    return result;
}

-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    return [self.title isEqualToString:[object title]] && 
    [self.author isEqualToString:[object author]];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [title release];
    [author release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Then to implement:

```
Asset *asset;
NSMutableArray *items = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

// First
asset = [[Asset alloc] init];
asset.title = @"Developer";
asset.author = @"John Smith";
[items addObject:asset];
[asset release];

// Second
asset = [[Asset alloc] init];
asset.title = @"Writer";
asset.author = @"Steve Johnson";
[items addObject:asset];
[asset release];

// Third
asset = [[Asset alloc] init];
asset.title = @"Developer";
asset.author = @"John Smith";
[items addObject:asset];
[asset release];

NSLog(@"Items: %@", items);

NSSet *distinctItems = [NSSet setWithArray:items];

NSLog(@"Distinct: %@", distinctItems);
```

And if you need an array at the end you can just call `[distinctItems allObjects]`

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd override the isEqual: method for Asset like this:

```
-(BOOL)isEqual:(Asset *)otherAsset {
    return [self.title isEqual:otherAsset.title] && [self.author isEqual:otherAsset.author];
}
```

Then, if you want to avoid placing duplicates in the array in the first place:

```
NSUInteger idx = [items indexOfObject:asset];  // tests objects for equality using isEqual:
if (idx == NSNotFound) [items addObject:asset];
```

If the array already contains duplicates, then any algorithm that finds them has a run time already worse than linear, but I think creating a new array and only adding unique elements like above is the best algorithm.  Something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *itemsWithUniqueElements = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[items count]];

for (Asset *anAsset in items) {
    if ([items indexOfObject:anAsset] == NSNotFound)
        [itemsWithUniqueElements addObject:anAsset];
}

[items release];
items = [itemsWithUniqueElements retain];
```

In the worst case scenario (all elements are already unique) the number of iterations is:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n =  n * (n+1) / 2
```

Which is still O(n^2) but is slightly better than @Justin Meiners' algorithm. No offense! :)

Comment: It can be solved linear O(n).  Because a hash table lookup amortizes to O(1), with extra space, you can do it in one loop.  Typical time vs. Space.

Comment: One more thing to add to that solution. You may use set instead of array after overriding -(BOOL)isEqual: method. then when you trying to add to set "duplicate" object it will not be added until you create your set as set that can contain duplicates...

Comment: @Ariel: You'll have to override `hash` as well if you want to use custom items in a set.

Comment: I've missed that. Haven't worked much with sets... :) Thanks for correcting.

Comment: The point about overriding hash is a good one.  I thought about going down that road (most correct) but opted for the simple concat string hashed for simplicity.

Comment: That's really great, I had no idea sets got you O(1) lookup.  I read a bit about it, and that you have to override hash as well, but how easy is it to write a hash function on a custom object that acts properly?  That's the part that seemed like it might be hard, but I haven't dug into it yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could do it
:

```
NSMutableArray* toRemove = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (Asset* asset1 in items)
    {
        for (Asset* asset2 in items)
        {
            if (asset1 != asset2)
            {
                if ([asset1.title isEqualToString:asset2.title] && [asset1.author isEqualToString:asset2.author])
                {
                    [toRemove addObject:asset2];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (Asset* deleted in toRemove)
    {
        [items removeObject:toRemove];
    }
```

Comment: OK but that's an n^2 algorithm which should generally be avoided.

Comment: You havent seen much code then :P It's just logical you check every item against every other item and compare the two. The reason why I have a toRemove is so I dont modify the items array while im iterating. @bryanmac yes it is n^2 and there might be some fancy other ways to do it, but this is simplest for me to think through also I doubt it will be at the scale where that would become a limitation.

Comment: I have seen plenty of code.  I just meant I was looking for a cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: agreed simple and works.  just pointing out an alternative.  I think the loop for the faster one is about the same code but might add a little more footprint (assuming duplicates are a minor case for yours).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like your custom NSObject subclasses to be considered equal when their names are equal you may implement `isEqual:` and `hash`. This will allow you to add of the objects to an `NSSet`/`NSMutableSet` (a set of distinct objects).

You may then easily create a sorted `NSArray` by using `NSSet`'s `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`method.

MikeAsh wrote a pretty solid piece about implementing custom equality: [Friday Q&A 2010-06-18: Implementing Equality and Hashing](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html)

Comment: Why did you post this answer twice? Flag duplicates as such when you find them rather than posting the same thing repeatedly.

Comment: Did I post it twice? I meant to post it in only once, could you flag one as a duplicate?