# How to implement -hash for -isEqual: with OR condition?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, equality

Let's say I've this `-isEqual:` method:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(MyObject*)aObject {
    if (![aObject isKindOfClass:[MyObject class]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return ([self.dateString isEqualToString:aObject.dateString] || [self.date isEqual:aObject.date]) &&
     ((!self.title && !aObject.title) || [self.title isEqualToString:aObject.title]);
}
```

So two objects are considered equal if either the `date` OR the `dateString` are equal and the `title` is equal. We assume here that `date` and `dateString` must not be nil, otherwise we'd have to check that, too. We further assume, there's no known relationship between `date` and `dateString`.

How can the corresponding `-hash` method be implemented in a way that it fulfills the requirement that two equal objects must have the same hash?

I tried to implement it by following this [great algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/254380/235297) but I'm having a hard time how to translate the OR condition of the two dates into an appropriate hash method.

(Admittedly, this question is somewhat academic because one can question whether this kind of equality does make any sense. Since I'm interested into finding a generic solution, please don't post an answer I should change my `isEqual:`. Except it can be formally proven that no suitable `-hash` method can exist.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create the hash value based on title alone completely ignoring date and dateString.

```
- (NSUInteger)hash
{
    return self.title.hash
}
```

This will ensure that equal objects always have the same hash. Objects with the same hash are not required to be equal.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes the solution is so easy you don't even think about it!

Comment: Nevertheless, of purely academic interest: if we had just the OR clause without the title equality check, what would be an appropriate hash method? Just return a constant?

Comment: How can I compute a hash that involves only the field which is equal to another field in a yet unknown object? you can't. A hash should involve all fields, be unique for each input, and ideally output a random distribution. Your OR equality definition is not compatible with that. For a few hash algorithms other than Bernstein see http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx