# NSPredicates and NSSets, how to reject things in the intersection of two sets?

Tags: objective-c

My code looks like:

```
NSPredicate* pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(title IN %@)", prev_set];
NSSet* remainingSet = [goal_set filteredSetUsingPredicate:pred ];
```

Where prev_set and goal_set are two different sets.  "title" in a property in the objects contained in both sets.

My objective is so that all goals are rejected if they have previously been met (each goal having a unique title).

If I have a predicate like "title in %@"  ALL of the objects in goal_set are rejected.  If I use "NOT("title in %@)", then NONE of the objects in goal_set are rejected.

If I print out both sets, I see that they clearly have some (but not all) objects in common (that is, their title is the same).

Am I completely confused about the use of "IN" for NSPredicates?  How would I accomplish my objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (title IN %@.title)", prev_set]`.

Your predicates assume that `prev_set` contains `NSString` objects, but according to your description, it contains objects that just have a string *property*, so it will never contain the titles themselves. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, removing the intersection of two sets `A` and `B` from `A` is the [relative complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29) of B in A, also called set difference, i.e. `A \ B`.

Luckly `NSMutableSet` features the set operation that you need, namely `minusSet:`

```
NSMutableSet *mutableGoalSet = [goal_set mutableCopy];
[mutableGoalSet minusSet:prev_set];
```

Of course, for this to work, you will have to implement `isEqual` and `hash` methods of your goal objects in order to make them identifiable by their title. (relevant: [Best practices for overriding isEqual: and hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254281/best-practices-for-overriding-isequal-and-hash))

Comment: This is incorrect. The definition of `minusSet:` is `- (void)minusSet:(NSSet *)otherSet` and has void return type, so I cannot see how your code will work.

Comment: @Echelon good catch, `minusSet:` acts on the set itself. I'm too used to pure collections, thank you for pointing it out. Fixed.