# NSDictionary, CustomKeys, Comparison

Tags: ios, objective-c, hash, comparison, nsdictionary

**SOLVED**

It seemed that both `-referenceDictionary` were not containing exact same information… Dang it ! Fixed it and now it works perfectly.

**Initial question**

It's been a few hours since I started struggling with this problem, here it is :

I have a `CustomClassA` which I use as NSDictionary key (obviously for the Object:ForKey: method).

At first it did not work at all, then I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254281/best-practices-for-overriding-isequal-and-hash), [that](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=73) and a few other stuffs around the web…

So I tried overriding both `-isEqual:` and `-hash` by doing as said (maybe a little less :p) :

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject
{
    if([anObject isKindOfClass:[self class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"HASH = %@", [anObject hash] == [self hash] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
        NSLog(@"DICT = %@", [[self referenceDictionary] isEqualToDictionary:[anObject referenceDictionary]] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
        return [[self referenceDictionary] isEqualToDictionary:[anObject referenceDictionary]];
    }
    return false;
}
- (NSUInteger)hash
{
    NSUInteger prime = 31;
    NSUInteger result = 1;
    NSArray* values = [referenceDictionary allValues];
    for(id k in values)
    {
        result = prime * result + [k hash];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Please, note that my NSDictionary will never contain `nil` values because I do take care of having these away.

Anyway, both of these methods do return `YES` on one of the NSDictionary entry when calling :`[myDict objectForKey:myObject]`.

But still, it seems `[myDict objectForKey:myObject]` returns `nil`, even after "setting" it myself…

If anyone has time to help me solving my pb I'd be thankful !

Regards,
Cehm

**EDIT:**
Ok, for the purpose of being a bit more clear about this issue. Lets assume two classes : `Artist` and `Single`.

Then I want to create a NSDictionary which contains an `Artist` as the `key` and this `Artist key` points to a `NSArray of "Single"s`.

For instance I'd have the following dictionary :

```
@{
artistA : @[song1, song2, song3],
artistB : @[songZ],
artistC : @[songF]
}
```

But now the thing is I want to create this dictionary like this :

```
for(Single* aSong in ArrayOfSingle)
    {
        Artist* anArtist = [[Artist alloc] initWithArtistName:aSong.artistName];
        if([data objectForKey: anArtist] == nil)
        {
            [data setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey: anArtist];
        } else
        {
            NSLog(@"exists");
        }
        [[data objectForKey: anArtist] addObject:aSong];
    }
```

Taken into account that data is mutable (Simple NSMutableDictionary) and that I won't ever change `anArtist` (assuming ARC still keeps its instance…).

**EDIT 2:**

I overrode NSCopying :

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] initWithDictionary:referenceDictionary];
}
```

As my `CustomClass` uses `initWithDictionary:` I assumed it would work just fine by doing this.

**EDIT 3:**

Here's the initWithDictionary:

```
-(id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*) dictionary
{
    self = [super initWithDictionary:dictionary];
    if(self)
    {
        referenceDictionary = dictionary;
        title = [super notNullObjectForKey:@"title"];
        name = [super notNullObjectForKey:@"name"];
        category = [super notNullObjectForKey:@"category"];
        artist = [super notNullObjectForKey:@"artist"];
        ad_city = [super notNullObjectForKey:@"ad_city"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I gather that `-referenceDictionary` returns an `NSDictionary` pointer. Further, it seems that that property is the only thing considered for equality. Have you considered making your `-hash` simply return `[referenceDictionary hash]` since your `-isEqual:` simply uses the `NSDictionary` implementation already? Also, have you properly implemented `NSCopying` for your class? Dictionaries copy their keys. Finally, is your class or its `referenceDictionary` mutable? If so, and you mutate it after using it as a dictionary key, then it will no longer match the key stored by the dictionary.

Comment: What is the use case of this object as a key?

Comment: @KenThomases Please check my edits. I just tried using [referenceDictionary hash] in the -hash method, but seems to do the same. referenceDictionary is immutable.

Comment: Does `-initWithDictionary:` just copy the input dictionary as-is, or does it tweak it?

Comment: @KenThomases Check edit3, I copied a bit of code in order to show you my init method

Comment: At this point, I can only recommend that you log `anArtist`, `[anArtist referenceDictionary]`, and iterate over `data` logging each key, each key's `referenceDictionary`, and whether the key equals `anArtist` and the key's `referenceDictionary` equals `anArtist`'s.