# How NSSet make sure the uniqueness of it objects?

Tags: ios, nsset

I want to know how `NSSet` make sure that it has only unique objects? When we try to add duplicate value, then on which criteria it decides that it has already this value? I want to know the underlying uniqueness criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSSet` uses your object's implementation of `isEqual:` method to decide object equality. It also uses `hash` to make the lookup much faster.

```
-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)other;
-(NSUInteger)hash;
```

When two objects are equal, their `hash` methods must return the same value (objects with the same `hash`, however, may not necessarily be equal to each other).

When your `hash` and `isEqual:` are [implemented properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/254281/335858), `NSSet` can decide the equality by checking only a handful of objects whose `hash` "collides" with the `hash` of the object you are adding to the set.

Comment: so your answer is: NSSet compares all its objects with the newly inserted one to see if it's already exists?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD Please re-read my answer, especially its last part, where I talk about checking a handful of objects based on their hash.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [Object Comparison](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introspection/Introspection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH9-SW61) in the official apple documentation. As you can see there most of the containers use `hash` to compare objects.

Answer (score 0):

**I want to know how NSSet make sure that it has only unique objects**

Whenever you try to add object it will check for hash value of all other existing objects inside of it. Based on that it will keep it as unique

If two objects are equal, they must have the same hash value

**When we try to add duplicate value, then on which criteria it decides that it has already this value?**

if the new object hash value matches the existing then it will be considered as dublicate

[Refer this Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all the set checks `hash` values of objects. If hashes are not equal it means that objects are guaranteed to be different. If hashes are equal it however doesn't mean that objects are neccessarily equal, so the set has to make sure and check their `isEqual:` methods