# Compare two objects in objective-c unit test assert

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

I am new in Testing in Objective-C but I have some experience in .NET with MSTest.

What is the best way to compare two objects in objective C using XCTAssert?

Example code is below:

```
- (void)testNumericValue_SaveAndLoad_ShouldSaveAndThenLoadIdenticalObject
{
    [_numericValue_1 saveToDatabaseWithKey:VALID_KEY_1];
    NumericValue *tmpNumericValue = [[NumericValue alloc] loadFromDatabaseWithKey:VALID_KEY_1];

    XCTAssertEqualObjects(tmpNumericValue, _numericValue_1);
}

- (void)testLoop_SaveAndLoad_ShouldSaveAndThenLoadIdenticalObject
{
    [_loop_1 saveToDatabase];
    Loop *tmpLoop = [[Loop alloc] loadFromDatabase];

    XCTAssertEqualObjects(tmpLoop, _loop_1);
}
```

I have many tests like this. I am sure that `save` and `load` functions work in a proper way. Some of this tests are passing, some are failing. What is the reason? 
I want this objects to have same properties values. I have to compare all of this properties one by one? Is there any "cleaner" way?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

> Some of them are passing, some are failing. What is the reason?

This is probably because you are using the default equality comparison.

> I want this objects to have same properties values. I have to compare all of this properties one by one? Is there any "cleaner" way?

Yes. Override `isEquals` to compare properties one-by-one, and `XCTAssertEqualObjects` will do the comparisons correctly:

```
-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)other {
     ...
}
```

Don't forget to override `hash` as well:

```
-(NSInteger)hash {
    ...
}
```

Here is a link to an [answer that discusses Best practices for overriding `isEqual:` and `hash`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/254281/335858).

Comment: If you are overriding `isEqual` then you must also override `hash`.