# NsArray ContainsObject is not working with Custom NsObject Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, compare, nsarray, nsobject

I am checking if my one of the array consist the `Nsobject` which i have created custom way.
i am using `ContainsObject` method.my problem is that contains object not working ever.even though i have same object in array its not returning the true value.

```
if([self.arrSelectedInterest containsObject:interest_ent])
```

i am also attaching the screen shot of my debug points which showing the value of the nsarray and comparing object and in that i found that `interest_ent` is a same object that contains in `self.arrSelectedInterest`
and still it always return false.

[image]

anyone have any idea how to check if my nsarray of custom nsobject contains specific Object?

Following is my hash and isEqual Method which i have overriden and also shwoing my property types in nsobejct.
@interface InterestEntity : JSONModel

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* InterestId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* Name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional>* Code;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional>* Description;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<Optional>* Hashtags;


- (NSUInteger)hash {
    NSUInteger result = 1;
    NSUInteger prime = 31;

    result = prime * result + [self.InterestId hash];
    result = prime * result + [self.Name hash];
    result = prime * result + [self.Code hash];
    result = prime * result + [self.Description hash];
    result = prime * result + [self.Hashtags hash];
    return result;
}
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    BOOL result = NO;

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
        result = [[self InterestId] isEqualToString:[object InterestId]] &&
        [[self Name] isEqualToString:[object Name]] &&
        [[self Code] isEqualToString:[object Code]] &&[[self Description] isEqualToString:[object Description]] && [[self Hashtags] isEqual:[object Hashtags]];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you properly implement the `isEqual:` and `hash` methods on your custom class?

Comment: nope i dont have that methods in my nsobject class

Comment: That's your problem. `containsObject:` uses `isEqual:` on the objects. The default implementation simply looks at the object pointers.

Comment: can you please explain how to override this in my nsobject?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254281/best-practices-for-overriding-isequal-and-hash

Comment: You don't handle the `nil` values. Those are causing `isEqual:` to return `NO`.

Comment: `containsObject` compare pointer reference, and if both points to same memory address then it will return `true`. But in your case the memory pointer are different( `even both contains same data` ) and because of that it is returning `false`.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar This is not correct. `containsObject:` does not compare pointers, it calls `isEqual:` on the objects.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `NSDictionary` to store the custom class object as value and some identifier as key. And you can check that this identifier is present or not.

Comment: @rmaddy I have faced same issue previously and I have done some research on that and found that it compares memory address. If memory address is same it will return true and if memory address is different it will return false. May be I am wrong. :)

Comment: @YogeshSuthar This is because the default implementation of `isEqual:` is to compare memory. It has nothing to do with `containsObject:`. It's all about the implementation of `isEqual:`. As long as there is a proper implementation of `isEqual:` in the custom class then you get the desired behavior.

Comment: @rmaddy What do you mean by `As long as there is a proper implementation of isEqual: in the custom class then you get the desired behavior` ? If memory address changes, how OP can handle the issue?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Look at the `isEqual:` method in question. That's one example of a (mostly) proper implementation.

Comment: To ovveride has and isEqual correctly that a look here http://nshipster.com/equality/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem is in implementing `isEqual` method in handling nullable objects

i.e. if two strings is null `isEqualToString:` will return false

Here is a proper implementation to handle all cases

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    if (object == self)
        return YES;
    if (!object || ![object isKindOfClass:[self class]])
        return NO;

    // not nullable fields
    if (![self.interestId isEqualToString:object.interestId])    
        return NO;   
    if (![self.name isEqualToString:object.name])    
        return NO;
    if (![self.code isEqualToString:object.code])    
        return NO;

    // nullable fields (2 if statements for more clean code)
    if (self.description != null && ![self.description isEqualToString:object.description])    
        return NO;    
    if (object.description != null && ![object.description isEqualToString:self.description])    
        return NO;

    if (self.hashtags != null && ![self.hashtags isEqualToString:object.hashtags])    
        return NO;    
    if (object.hashtags != null && ![object.hashtags isEqualToString:self.hashtags])    
        return NO;  


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Any idea.. how this method gets called?